# AJAX response text for success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Right now I'm modifying my AJAX request to be asynchronous but I wanted to know if there was something similar to `var reponse = $.ajax({` in success. Before I had my code as:

```
     var response = $.ajax({
           type : "GET",
           url : url,
           data : parameters,
           cache : false,
           async : false
    }).responseText;

return response;
```

I tried doing using the first data argument but that just returns the parameters. Is there something similar I can use in success?

```
success : function(response) {
     callBack(response); 
}
```

Comment: callBack(response.responseText); should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks! I tried it but It's coming back as undefined.

Comment: Ah, shoot. Try logging your response an look at it! `success: function(response) { console.log(response); }`

Comment: Ok on my console all the XML is there but when I'm debugging it's undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Because the request is asynchronous you cannot just return the response.

jQuery uses something called "promises", which you can return instead:

```
function getUser(id) {
    return $.ajax({
        url: "/user",
        data: { id:id },
    });
}
```

So, whenever you want to get a user you just call the function:

```
var userRequest = getUser(123);
```

The `userRequest` variable now contains a "future promise". In other words, sometime in the future it will be ready for you to use it.

You cannot use it straight away but you can create a function that will run when it finally is ready. That is done using the `.done()` method:

```
userRequest.done(function (user) {
    console.log("The user " + user.name + " has been loaded!");
});
```

If you, for example, also want to load the user's profile alongside the user then you can create two requests and then use the `$.when()` method:

```
var userRequest    = getUser(123).
    profileRequest = getProfileForUser(123);

$.when(userRequest, profileRequest).done(function (user, profile) {
    console.log(user.name + " is " + profile.age + " years old");
});
```

Read more about [promises over at jQuery](https://learn.jquery.com/code-organization/deferreds/).